# Degree of extensions and their composite

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $F<E$ and $F<K$ be finite extensions and assume that $EK$ is defined as composite of two fields. I need to show that $[EK:F] \leq [E:F][K:F]$, with equality if $[E:F]$ and $[K:F]$ are relatively prime.

I am stuck with even the less than or equal to part, and also I couldn't see the thing about the case being these two relatively prime.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: $E \otimes_F K = \{ \sum_j a_j \otimes_F b_j, a_j \in E, b_j \in K\}$ is a ring containing both $E,K$ and we have a surjective morphism $E \otimes_F K \to EK$ which is $\sum_j a_j \otimes_F b_j \mapsto \sum_j a_jb_j$. Thus it reduces to understand the construction of $E \otimes_F K$ and that it is a $[E:F][K:F]$ dimensional $F$-vector space

Answer (score 4):

Since $E$ and $K$ are finite extensions of $F$, they are algebraic and finitely generated. So, we can write $E = F(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $K = F(b_1,\dots,b_m)$ for some algebraic elements $a_1,\dots,a_n,b_1,\dots,b_m$. The composite field $EK$ is then equal to $F(a_1,\dots,a_n,b_1,\dots,b_m)$.

Now, $[EK : F] = [EK : E] [E : F]$, so it suffices to show that $[EK : E] \leq [K : F]$. Let $E_0 = E$ and $E_i = E_{i-1}(b_i)$ for each $1 \leq i \leq m$. Note that $E_m = EK$. Let $F_0 = F$ and $F_i = F_{i-1}(b_i)$ for each $1 \leq i \leq m$. In particular, $F_i \subseteq E_i$ for each $i$. Also note that $K = F_m$. Hence,
$$
\begin{align}
[EK : E] = [E_m : E_0] &= [E_m : E_{m-1}] \cdots [E_1 : E_0], \quad \text{and}\\
[K : F] = [F_m : F_0] &= [F_m : F_{m-1}] \cdots [F_1 : F_0].
\end{align}
$$
For each $1 \leq i \leq m$,
$$
\begin{align}
[E_i : E_{i-1}] = [E_{i-1}(b_i): E_{i-1}] &= \deg \min(E_{i-1},b_i)\\
&\leq \deg \min(F_{i-1},b_i)\\
&= [F_{i-1}(b_i) : F_{i-1}]\\
&= [F_i : F_{i-1}]
\end{align}
$$
Hence,
$$
[EK : E] = \prod_{i=1}^m [E_i : E_{i-1}] \leq \prod_{i=1}^m [F_i : F_{i-1}] = [K : F].
$$
Thus, $[EK:F] \leq [E:F] [K:F]$.

---

$$
[EK:F] = [EK:E][E:F] \implies [E:F] \mid [EK:F],\\
[EK:F] = [EK:K][K:F] \implies [K:F] \mid [EK:F].
$$
$$
\gcd([E:F],[K:F]) = 1 \implies [E:F][K:F] \mid [EK:F].
$$
$$
\therefore [E:F][K:F] \leq [EK:F].
$$
By the previous part,
$$
[EK:F] \leq [E:F] [K:F].
$$
Hence, $[EK:F] = [E:F] [K:F]$ if $[E:F]$ and $[K:F]$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score -2):

Divide the inequality by one of the factors on the right; you should be able to subsequently simplify the left-hand side by using the [product formula for towers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#The_multiplicativity_formula_for_degrees). Use the [PET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) for the numerator field on the right-hand side, so that both sides of the inequality turn into the degree of an algebraic element only the one on the left side is considered over a larger base field...

For the second part, remember your knowledge of arithmetic and elementary number theory: in particular recall that $a,b\mid n$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ imply $ab\mid n$. What are $a,b,n$ in this problem?